# Open Select after a click on label

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking for a way to open a Select (not native) component from Material UI after a click on the label with `htmlFor` specified.

```
<label htmlFor='menu'>Label to open Menu</label>

<MUISelect inputProps={{id: 'menu'}} native={false}>{options}</MUISelect>
```

Obviously it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

There are two main aspects to this problem:

1. You need to get the `id` onto the same element that has the click-handler for opening the menu.
2. The element with the click-handler is a `div` and not an `input`. Labels do not automatically trigger the click event of the labelled element when it is not an input element.

The first aspect can be solved by using `SelectDisplayProps`:

```
SelectDisplayProps={{ id: "menu" }}
```

The second aspect can be solved with a custom label component:

```
import React from "react";

const LabelForClickableDiv = ({ htmlFor, ...other }) => {
  const onClick = () => {
    document.getElementById(htmlFor).click();
  };
  return <label htmlFor={htmlFor} onClick={onClick} {...other} />;
};
export default LabelForClickableDiv;
```

Here's a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import LabelForClickableDiv from "./LabelForClickableDiv";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <LabelForClickableDiv htmlFor="menu">
            Label to open Menu
          </LabelForClickableDiv>
          <Select
            value={value}
            onChange={event => {
              setValue(event.target.value);
            }}
            SelectDisplayProps={{
              id: "menu"
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default SimpleSelect;
```

[image: Edit Select with non-MUI label]

Comment: I assume the CodeSandbox example was functioning at one point in time. However, it is no longer working and I am unable to get it working locally with material-ui 4.11.0.

Comment: @MikeLoffland I've fixed the sandbox by putting the version to 4.7.0. This was broken by [4.7.1](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v4.7.1) when [Select was changed to open on mouse-down](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/17978) instead of click.